# check if a file exists where basename is varies

Tags: python

I am trying to find if a file exists in a given directory. The first part of the filename (`basename` with `basename.ext` convention) is variable, but `ext`=sys.

So, I am doing this:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".sys"):
        sysnm = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
        syst = True
        break
if not syst:
    print("SYS input does not exists! Exiting")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Problem is, as obvious, it will search all files until it finds one. Not that it takes any considerable time for each dir(in my dirs, I will have ~500 files maximum), but still I am looking if there is any cleverer way.

Comment: Why not just use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)?

Comment: @vaultah: It looks like I am doing almost same thing with the links you provided. They will also run for all files to check, as I said my code is doing. May you comment if one is better than other.

Comment: I doubt you can avoid looping altogether. Though `glob`-based solution from the second link doesn't have any *explicit* loops.

Comment: @BaRud you can use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to eliminate `os.path.isfile` and avoid memory issues for huge number of directories.